# How to end borrow when an Option is None

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following code will fail the borrow checker:

```
fn at(&mut self, i: usize) -> Option<&T> {
    match self.vector.get(i) {
        Some(x) => Some(x),
        None => {
            self.mutate_vector_to_have_more_stuff();
            self.at(i)
        }
    }
}
```

I can see why: `self.vector` is still borrowed lexically through to the end, so I cannot borrow `self` again.

What is the right way to structure my scopes?  The borrow persists into the match because I actually use it in the `Some(x)` branch, but in the `None` branch I no longer use the borrowed value, because there was no value to borrow to begin with.

I have a rewritten version that works for this specific case:

```
if i >= self.vector.len() {
    self.mutate_vector_to_have_more_stuff();
    self.at(i)
} else {
    self.vector.get(i)
}
```

This works because using `len` means that I witness the "nothing to borrow" before even trying to borrow anything, and then only borrow in the nested scope.  I'm concerned that this wouldn't work in every case where I have an `Option`, though, there may not be a boolean-only variant of every `Option`-returning API.

Is there a way to restructure this code to work but still using the `get` call as the main way to know if there is a value or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem due to the way lifetimes currently work in (stable) Rust. The standard solution would look something like this in your case:

```
fn at(&mut self, i: usize) -> Option<&T> {
    if let Some(x) = self.vector.get(i) {
        return Some(x);
    }
    // mutate self.vector
    self.at(i)
}
```

As you can probably see, the immutable borrow of `self.vector` only lasts as long as the *if* block, so a mutable borrow on it is possible as soon as it ends.

That said, Rust nightly has a work-around for this issue, if you want to enable the unstable [non-lexical lifetimes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43234) feature. Your existing code should work fine if you just include the line `#![feature(nll)]` at the top of your crate.